# Column values and Column header iteraton calculation

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel sheet setup as below:

```
avgdegf |  50 | 55| 60| 65| 70| 75| 80 |

76      |

68      |

39      |
```

note: the values under the values 50,55,60,65,70,75, and 80 are empty.

What I am trying to achieve is filling these values based off of the number values in the column. so If avgdegf value is greater than (header number) of the specific column than do (avgdegf-header number) else the value is 0 and put the value in the specific row for example.

```
 avgdegf |  50 | 55| 60| 65| 70| 75| 80 |

76       | 26  |21 |16 |11 | 6 | 1 | 0  |

68       | 18  |13 | 8 |11 | 0 | 0 | 0  | 

39       | 0   |0  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0  |
```

This above is what I expect to get, but instead I just get:

```
Python: ValueError: The Truth Value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this? Thanks!

Here is a chunk of my code below:

```
df_avgdegf = df["avgdegf"]
x=50
for x in range(50, 81):

        if df_avgdegf > x:
                df[x]= (df_avgdegf)-x
        else:
                df[x]=0

        df.head()

        df_cdd = df[x]
        df_cdd = pd.DataFrame(df_cdd)



        writer = ExcelWriter('thecddhddtestque.xlsx')
        df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=False)
        writer.save()
        x += 1
```

Comment: The line `if df_avgdegf > x` is the immediate problem as you're testing a boolean array which might have a mix of true and false values. It looks like you'll run into other problems when that's fixed though. For example, `df[x]= (df_avgdegf)-x` doesn't make sense as you're setting a value of a series to another series which doesn't make sense.

Comment: do you know how I go about these calculations using dfs? Any suggestions? I have tried multiple methods in trying to acheive this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've assumed your data in a csv file.
The same principles would apply if you are using excel reader.

data.csv:

```
avgdegf,50,55,60,65,70,75,80
76,,,,,,
68,,,,,,
39,,,,,,
```

get your data into a dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

so your df will look like this:

```
   avgdegf  50  55  60  65  70  75  80
0       76 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
1       68 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
2       39 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
```

the next steps with this code will do the trick:

```
# we want to get the numerical columns into the dataframe
df.iloc[0,1:] = df.columns[1:] 
df = df.fillna(method ='ffill')

df =df.astype(np.float64) # cast type for next steps

df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:].sub(df['avgdegf'],axis='index')  # 1.) see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.subtract.html
df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:].applymap(lambda x: 0 if x > 0 else x) # 2.) set positve values to zero
df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:].applymap(np.abs) # 3.) since we went reverse we now take np.abs()
df.set_index('avgdegf',inplace=True)
```

which produces:

```
         50  55  60  65  70  75  80
avgdegf                            
76       26  21  16  11   6   1   0
68       18  13   8   3   0   0   0
39        0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: When I try to implement this code I get the error: 'could not convert string to float: avgdegf'

Comment: I am a bit confused, as to where in the code that you presented is the calculations for   "If avgdegf value is greater than (header number) of the specific column than do (avgdegf-header number) else the value is 0" taking place in? Thanks!

Comment: So these steps take place across 3 lines of code and it starts where i call .sub(). This is an abbreviation of .subtract(). see: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.subtract.html. It goes in 3 steps. 1.) for simplicity I do the subtraction the other way round (header number - avgdegf)   2.) set the *positive* values to zero  3.) now take absolute value np.abs()

Comment: Regarding 'could not convert string to float' : avgdegf,  the reason is probably due to the datatype of the values that have been read into the dataframe. Use df.dtypes to show you the datatypes of the columns. I wonder is 'avgdegf' your column header or a value in your dataframe?. Make it the header and you should be able to convert the other values '76','68' etc. to 78,68 as float, or int if you want. Specifc column conversion df['avgdegf'] =df['avgdegf'].astype(np.float64)

Comment: Edit:Got it solved. but How would i implement this code if i had another column in front of avgdegf. for example if i had date column in front of avgdegf. and I would still want to calculate the same exact thing. when I try it i get  error: 'could not convert string to float: date'. Thanks

Comment: You should then slice your dataframe to filter to the columns that you need to act on. Similar to this. df.iloc[:,1:]. which takes all the rows and then for columns position 1 to the end and excludes the column in position 0. Perhaps beginning to stray into a new question, "dataframe slicing", which maybe is best asked in a new thread?

Comment: Last but not least it seems like the code result just removes the column avgdegf and just displays the remaining numbered columns with the calculated values. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90686/discussion-between-dickster-and-techno04335).

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps cleaner syntax and demonstrates the cool "broadcasting" of numpy. Ultimately the same result as the other Answer.

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

df.fillna(1,inplace=True)
print df.head()
df = df.astype(np.int)

b = df.iloc[:,1:].values
a =  df.columns[1:].values.astype(int)

print a.shape
print b.shape

print a*b
print df['avgdegf'].values
print df['avgdegf'].values[:,np.newaxis]


method1 = (a*b) - df['avgdegf'].values[:,np.newaxis]
#or
method2 = ((a*b).T - df['avgdegf'].values).T


df.iloc[:,1:] = method1

#df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:].applymap(lambda x : np.abs(0) if x > 0 else np.abs(x))
#OR
df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:].clip_upper(0).abs()
```